# How to embed and display a png with FlashDevelop, Haxe and Swfmill

Tags: flash, flashdevelop, haxe

I am having trouble getting a png file to display in a simple Flash application I am building using **Haxe** and FlashDevelop.

Step taken

- Added the png file to my project.
- Added the png to the library
- Set the option to embed as a bitmap
- Set an Id for the object "PlayerBitmap"
- Verified that the xml generated looks correct

I then try to display the embedded image:

```
var bitmap:Bitmap;
bitmap = new PlayerBitmap();
bitmap.x = 200;
bitmap.y = 200; 
addChild(bitmap);
```

The code compiles and generates a swf file but the image is not shown.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue by creating two simple test projects to load an image.
The first worked and the second failed.
There was one difference between the projects one had a package.

The working project my Main does not have a package it is compiled like this
-main Main

The failing project is identical except the main is in a package and it compiles like this
-main org.alexjeffery.Main

To get the image to load when my main was in the org.alexjeffery package I set the image name to org.alexjeffery.PlayerBitmap instead of PlayerBitmap.

I have now written a tutorial on how to [embed images using FlashDevelop and Haxe](http://www.alexjeffery.org/programming/embed-a-custom-bitmap-using-haxe-and-flashdevelop/).

Comment: would be nicer if the link still worked. Maybe forgot to pay his domain-name renewal?

Answer (score 0):

what do you get when you trace

- `bitmap`
- `bitmap.bitmapData.rect`
- some random pixels with `bitmap.bitmapData.getPixel`

**update 1:** is your PNG maybe interlaced, or anything else like that? swfmill has problems with interlaced images, if i remember well ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: Here are the traces:

Bitmap: [object Bitmap]
bitmap.bitmapData.rect: (x=0, y=0, w=20, h=20)
bitmap.bitmapData.getPixel(5, 5): 0

The getPixel is not what I would expect. It is black when the source at that point is red.

I had a black background and when I changed it to white I can now see a black square where my image should be.

For some reason it is loading a black image and not the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, open the directory of the project, then go to the source folder, and then paste the *.png files there. They will automatically be detected by FlashDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this page on the Haxe manual:
http://haxe.org/manual/target-flash-resources.html

Basically you need:

```
@:bitmap("relative/path/to/myfile.png") 
class MyBitmapData extends BitmapData { }
```